# Object of class wpdb could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get an organisation's ID by giving its name.
I have the following code:

```
$orgid= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT organisationid FROM $wpdb->$table_name1 WHERE organisationname=' " . $organisation . "'");
```

This line returns this error:
Catchable fatal error:

```
Object of class wpdb could not be converted to string
```

I wish to echo this ID onto the page.

I have read the codex but do not understand. How can I fix this?

Comment: there's a space in here `' " . $organisation . "'` remove it. `'" . $organisation . "'` and make sure this is spelled correctly `organisaitonname` - might be `organisationname` in your db? that's how it should be spelled anyway. and do a var_dump on that variable. use `trim()` also should there be whitespace introduced.

Comment: Hi Fred, I have done this but it did not fix my problem. Thanks

Comment: could be in `FROM $wpdb->$table_name1` then. From what I found so far in regards to the error message, try using braces around it ie: `FROM {$wpdb->$key}` as per a finding here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/object-of-class-wpdb-could-not-be-converted-to-string-1

Comment: while I was Googling this ^, an answer's been posted with the same method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to use variable variables inside the string, remember to wrap it with curly braces:

```
"SELECT organisaitonid FROM {$wpdb->$table_name1} WHERE organisaitonname = '" . $organisation . "'"
                       //    ^  important       ^
```

Note: Just make sure that the value of `$table_name1` does correspond to `$wpdb`'s properties of course so that it matches.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks! Another note on this is that you don't need the $wpdb-> in {$wpdb->$table_name1}

Answer (score 2):

Try also

```
$wpdb->table_name1
```

instead of:

```
$wpdb->$table_name1
```

without dollar "$"